# A method to evaluate functional roots of $e^x$

Tags: functions, polynomials, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I've an idea to find exact function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=e^x$. But it involves solving complicated systems of non-linear equations, the skills for which I don't have.

Here's how I intend to do it:

The Taylor series of $e^x$ around $x=0$ is:
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+......$$
If we assume our required function $f(x)$ to be:
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+......a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$
i.e. a polynomial of degree $n$. From that we can get $f(f(x))$.

I think it can be proved that the  $f(f(x))$ that we get will have terms containing all the powers of $x$ ranging from $x^{(n^2)}$ to $x^0$ (i.e. a constant term). Now, when $x$ is small the higher power terms don't matter, so we ignore the terms containing $x^{n+1}$, $x^{n+2}$.........$x^{(n^2)}$. After ignoring these terms, the remaining terms contain these powers of $x$: $x^0$, $x$, $x^2$,........$x^n$. Now, we compare the coefficients of these terms with the coefficients of the like powers of $x$ in the Taylor series of $e^x$. In this way, we get $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ variables.

Now, we solve these equations to get the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2......a_n$. These will be functions of $n$ (I think). Now we apply $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ to these functions to get the exact value of coefficients.

It would be a stressful task to solve those non-linear equations to get the coefficients in terms of $n$. But would this method work?

EDIT: Even if $x$ is not small, the higher power terms can be ignored because the higher power terms will have very large factorials in their denominators. Also, we're applying $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ in the end and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=0$ for any finite $x$.

EDIT:By using a first degree polynomial, I got this function, which when applied twice to $c$ gives you exactly $a^c$(not approximately because I didn't have to ignore any terms in case of a first degree polynomial) :
$$x\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$$
 Problem is it itself depends upon $c$, so I guess there's a family of these square-root functions.
Similarly, the $n^{th}$ root of $a^x$ at $x=c$ is:
$$x(a^c\log_ea)^{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a^c\log_ea)^{\frac{k}{n}}}$$
$$=x(a^c\log_ea)^{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)((a^c\log_ea)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}{a^c\log_ea-1}$$

At $x=c$, my square-root function is: $$c\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$$. Now substituting this in place of $x$ is my function gives, $$\left(c\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}\right)\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$$

$$=ca^c\log_ea+a^c(1-c\log_ea)$$

$$=a^c$$

Comment: The approximating polynomial of $f(f(x))$ is of degree $n^2$, not $n^n$. This said, the method will probably lead to intractable computation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, Thanks for that. And I don't think either that any person   alive can do these calculations.

Comment: Maybe a person can't, but a computer might for finite (small enough) $n$

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yeah, but only numerical calculations. If only a computer could work with symbols to give us the coefficients as a function of $n$.........

Comment: Another problem that arises when you use this method is the fact that, sure, you get $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ variables; but they're not linear, in fact, the highest degree present in each equation is $n+1$; and as such, one should not expect only one solution to each such system and especially not exact solutions (if $n+1>4$)

Comment: It is not straightforward for a function to have square roots (see e.g. [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-square-root) post)

Comment: @Harry49 But there seems to be nothing wrong in the method except the computations.

Comment: The taxing part about this, is that you'll get a formal power series, but it's essentially impossible to prove it has a nonzero radius of convergence. Look at this post here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge
It derives a power series of $f(f(x)) = \sin$ in a similar manner that you're trying to derive one for $e^x$. However, this formal power series, DOES NOT CONVERGE. So it's essentially, not very useful. At least, in complex analysis, or as a Taylor series.

Comment: @james.nixon But, if I get smaller and smaller coefficients of the farther terms by this method, then the series will obviously converge. I think that it'll definitely converge. And, look at the two functions which I've written in the last. They're not approximate roots, they're exact functional roots. But the problem is they themselves depend upon the number on which the function is being applied. Could we have a family of these functions?

Comment: You might be getting an asymptotic series, exactly how $f(f(x)) = \sin$ is an asymptotic series. It appears to be getting closer to convergence, but it actually diverges. I can't know for sure, but I'm just stating from experience, I haven't actually $proved$ your series diverges. I've just frequently encountered arguments in fractional iteration involving Taylor series, and it's very hard to make work. And when the Taylor series is solved, once it seems absolute, proving that the radius of convergence of this well founded Taylor series is non zero, proves all things considered, impossible.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but you're doing something VERY similar to what is done in this page http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=3&highlight=andrew%27s+slog . In this page they do in fact construct the tetration function $^ze$ and its inverse $\text{slog}(z)$, using Taylor series, but proving that the radius of convergence is nonzero is still an open problem. And they're solving a system of equations of size $n$ involving the coefficients of a Taylor series, and they successfully let $n\to\infty$ and it all converges, but they can't $prove$ it converges.

Comment: So even if your conjectured root function is a root function, that tends to be besides the point. I can't imagine a manner of actually proving it converges. And if it did, it would probably be on a domain that isn't very useful. It's already very well known that $f(f(z)) = e^z$ has no entire solutions, and if defined, is defined on a very wonky domain. Even more evidence that finding, and proving a nonzero radius of convergence, is going to be harder.

Comment: @james.nixon The root function I've written in the last absolutely converges. Just apply that function twice to $c$ and you'll get exactly $a^c$.

Comment: No, it doesn't because there is no entire solution to that equation, and your equation is entire. Plus you make less and less sense. The $n$'th root of $a^x$ at $x=c$ while you still contain an equation involving $x$ is meaningless. Where are you placing the substitutions to create an $n$'th root; in the $x$? Well then you're just solving a linear equation. It makes little to no sense what you're saying, fractional iteration is a very advanced subject, you're not going to get a solution to the square root of $e^x$ using an equation as simple as that. Someone would've done it years ago.

Comment: @james.nixon You're not getting what I'm saying. This is the square-root function that I've written:$$ x\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$$. Now, you just substitute $x=c$ in this function and get the answer in terms of $c$. Now, again substitute this answer in place of $x$ in that function and you'll get EXACTLY $a^c$. If you don't, then I'm voting for this question to close myself.

Comment: @james.nixon I'm doing it. At $x=c$, my function is: $c\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$. Now substituting this is my function again, we get: $\left(c\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}\right)\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+\frac{a^c(1-c\log_ea)}{\sqrt{a^c\log_ea}+1}$. This evaluates to $a^c$.